# Textbox background color not changing after save

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

input box not background not change after save

```
    function removeMsg() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.NotificationViewerSucess').stop(true, true).fadeOut()
            $('.NotificationViewerError').stop(true, true).fadeOut()
            $('#TextBox1').stop(true, true).css({ 'background-color': 'LightGray' });
        }, 4000)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be with dynamic ID, try this:-

```
$('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').stop(true,true).css({ 'background-color': 'LightGray' });
```

Or else set, `ClientIdMode="Static"` in your textbox like this:-

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" ClientIdMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```